# Meaning of mathematical proof in terms of logic.

Tags: logic

Generally, when I have a proof, where I from assumptions and some statement derive bunch of other statements, i.e.:

```
Assumption 1
Assumption 2
...
Assumption n
------------
Statement 1
Statement 2
...
Statement m
```

What does it means in terms of logic? Is it the proof metalogically roughly something like following statement (sorry for mixing logic and metalogic)?

$$
(\text{Assumption1}\land\text{Assumption2}\land\dots\land\text{AssumptionN}) \Rightarrow\\(\text{Statement1}\Leftrightarrow \text{Statement2}\Leftrightarrow \dots\Leftrightarrow \text{StatementM})
$$

**Example:**

Consider statement $2na=2mb$ under assumption $n=m$. Does it means that when $n=m$, following statements are equivalent?
$$
2na=2mb\\
 na=mb\\
 2a=2b\\
  a=b
$$

Comment: You apply rules of inference to assumptions to derive new statements that are consequence of the first ones. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't get the biconditional between the inferred statements.

Simple counterexample:

A valid proof is:

$P \land Q \land R$

$\therefore$

$P \land Q$

$P$

but $P \land Q$ and $P$ are not equivalent

What you *do* have is that:

$(P \land Q \land R) \to ((P \land Q) \land P)$

is a tautology. Or, what is the same thing, that:

$P \land Q \land R \Rightarrow (P \land Q) \land P$

is a meta-logical truth

In general, a valid proof means that all the assumptions together imply all and each of the derived statements, i.e. that:

$(Assumption_1 \land ... \land Assumption_n) \to (Statements_1 \land ... \land Statement_m)$

is a tautology, i.e. that we have:

$(Assumption_1 \land ... \land Assumption_n) \Rightarrow (Statement_1 \land .... \land Statement_m)$

i.e. that we have all of:

$(Assumption_1 \land ... \land Assumption_n) \Rightarrow Statement_1$

...

$(Assumption_1 \land ... \land Assumption_n) \Rightarrow Statement _m$

We can also say that:

$\{ Assumption_1, ... , Assumption_n \} \vDash (Statement_1 \land ... \land Statement_m)$

or, that we have all of:

$\{ Assumption_1 , ... , Assumption_n \} \vDash Statement_1$

...

$\{ Assumption_1 , ... , Assumption_n \vDash Statement _m$